# detect host machine cpu type

Tags: virtualization, vmware-player, virtual-host

Support I'm running a VMWARE virtual machine (Called Machine A) on a host server which we call it B.

I want to know are there any methods that applications/users inside A (the VM) can detect CPU type/model of their host machine (Server B)? For example, I want the application inside the VM to be able to tell that the host has an Intel Core i5 6600 CPU.

Comment: Your question does not make sense.  The fact you are using a VMWare product means your CPU is a x86 product.  What do you specifically mean by "CPU type"?

Comment: @Ramhound I mean is there a method that I can understand my VM is running in a server which have cpu with model Intel Core i5 6600? I mean access details of server machine from Virtual Machine?

Comment: Highly doubtful. It would require punching a hole in the VM; while such things happen, they are often unintentional and considered bugs (with potential security implications).

Comment: Well, in a VirtualBox guest it is possible to query the CPU. It will show the details of the host cpu. But this doesn't mean that the host is exposed. It is just the CPU so that virtualization is sped up.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling So, there are no know tool for this?

Comment: @TJJ VirtualBox allows changing settings related to the CPU that is exposed to the guest. There are instructions in various places online for how to do that to install Windows 10 on older versions of VirtualBox, for example.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Of course you can change it. There is no 100% way that this will ALWAYS work (that means you could present a fake processor to the guest). But the default settings of VMware expose the CPU information to the guests.

Answer (score -2):

Yes. Supposed you have set the correct virtualization mode, this is the situation by default. The guest will see the same CPU information as the host.

Comment: How do you specifically do what you described.  The author seems to have a desire to identify the CPU running in a "<virtualized environment>".  What they mean by that isn't even clear.

Comment: Yes, it is clear. He is running a guest system and from inside the guest he wants to see cpu the host is running. This is possible because of the way that virtualization works. The tools however depend on the guest operating system. On a Windows guest it would be for example cpuz and on a linux system I would use cpuinfo.